# "Edit tags" not clickable (disappears) when on the next line

Tags: bug, tags, edits

When the tag names are long enough to have the same width as the question, the "edit tags" link appears on the next line.

[image]

However, the link only appears when I am in the line with the tags. As soon as I move elsewhere - in particular when I try to click on "edit tags" - the link disappears.

([The example](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/758948/proof-of-equivalent-characterizations-of-compact-operators) in the screenshot is from math.SE.)

Comment: [Example on Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328497/creating-app-with-min-sdk-level-8-and-target-sdk-level-15) - found using [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/186668/questions-having-longest-tags). Interesting enough, I can "catch" the edit tags link quite easily but it still looks weird.

Comment: [Something strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7mC6.gif) does still happen, although no matter how hard I tried, I wasn't able to find the exact right combo of tags to make "edit tags" completely unclickable, as they wrap strangely, at least on MSE. ([This](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296193/user-card-senses-danger-when-chasing-tricky-edit-tags-runs-for-dear-life#comment961247_296202) is the comment referenced in that gif.)