# What is the "nlcode" in Newsletter email?

Tags: support, email, newsletter

Just noticed that all the links in the Newsletter email sent to me contain "nlcode" parameter in the querystring, e.g.

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296193/user-card-senses-danger-when-chasing-tricky-edit-tags-runs-for-dear-life?newsletter=1&nlcode=xxxxxx%7cyyyy
```

Not sure if it's private info so replaced actual details, the format is A|B, where A is some integer (not my user ID here on in the Network profile), and B is probably some hex value.

What is this value and what is it used for?

Comment: Well, tracking of course. I guess Stack Overflow can somehow analyze the effectiveness of their newsletters this way. Hopefully, a developer will come along and provide the details. Of course, the `newsletter=1` already provides this, but perhaps the code identifies your particular subscription?

Comment: We could determine if it was private or not by comparing our nlcode's but, unfortunately, I don't actually get the newsletter.

Comment: @Glorfindel you have MSE newsletter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nlcode` stands for newsletter code (nl - news-letter) - see how that works?

The code itself allows us to figure out what exact newsletter subscription caused a specific visit to the site.

As surmised by the OP, this allows us to track newsletter effectiveness, performance and to run A/B tests and experiments on those in order to improve them.

---

As I've been asked about the format - which takes an `a|b` form - the `|` is simply a delimiter, the `a` stands for the subscription id and the `b` is its HMAC (because we don't trust people and email providers to not mess around with a url... we always verify).